# Tumblr - How to link to photo permalink from Tumblr dashboard?

Tags: tumblr, links, blog, photos

I run a few photo blogs on Tumblr. I also follow a variety of similar blogs. I have noticed that when I click certain photo posts, the images open inside Tumblr as Lightboxes. But sometimes, the permalink page of the post is opened in a new page.

Is there any specific option that I can turn on the same for my blogs ?

So far I have only been able to add permalink to photo caption only.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link on a photo by clicking the one encircled with red:

[image]

Add your desired link on the space provided once you click on that button. If you want to use the photo's permalink, upload the photo first, then get the permalink, and add the permalink on that button.

If you don't want to do those tedious stuff, set your permalink in the gear at top right, and use the link you've created.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that tip. But I almost always post Photo sets and when I add two or more images, that link icon changes to Caption icon. Sorry I wasn't clear with the question.